# How do we get an Outlook Recipient's actual email address?

Tags: email, outlook

Hoping to get a little help with this one that has stumped me today:

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
Outlook.Recipients recips = mail.Recipients;
string toField = recips[1].Address;
```

I'm not getting the actual address returned.  I've tried suggestions on the MSDN site with no luck.  Specifically, the PR_SMTP_ADDRESS service is dead:

```
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _ 
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
```

Thanks very much in advance for any help you all can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Recipient.AddressEntry` to get the `AddressEntry` object. Check if the `AddressEntry.Type` property, if it is **SMTP**, just use `AddressEntry.Address`. If it is **EX**, use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress.`

Comment: Be sure to handle errors correctly - Recipient.AddressEntry will return null for unresolved recipients or raise an error if the address entry cannot be opened.