# How to get sender's email when Email type is EX for Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, com

I am trying to get sender's email address for an Outlook mailbox through C# code. I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496931/how-do-we-get-an-outlook-recipients-actual-email-address) but I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for `senderEmail = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` line. My code is as follows:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
Outlook.MailItem olMail = new Outlook.MailItem();

if (olMail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
{

   var objReply = olMail.Reply();
   var objRecipient = objReply.Recipients[1]; 

   var strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID;

   var objAddressentry = oNS.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId);
   string senderEmail = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

I will appreciate any help.

If it is of any help, I came across [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akashb/2008/12/19/how-to-get-details-about-a-exchange-user-in-outlook-2007-outlook-2003/), but my `AddressEntryUserType` comes as `olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry`, which is why the control doesn't go inside the If branch.

Comment: Your code converted to VBA works fine on my test machine.

Comment: I am trying to convert from VBA code to C#. That's why it must have run fine. How does the code run in C# ? It throws error ?

Comment: Sorry I have no time to test your c# code but I think you'd try to add "string" before senderEmail.

Comment: @VictorIvanidze Do you have link to convert from VBScript to C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed earlier by, my code is correct. It throws the  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception for `objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()`, when `AddressEntryUserType` for `Sender` is of  `olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry` type. Modified code is as follows:

```
if (olMail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
   {

         var objReply = olMail.Reply();
         Outlook.Recipient objRecipient = objReply.Recipients[1]; 
         string strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID;
         Outlook.AddressEntry objAddressentry = oNS.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId);

         if (objAddressentry != null)
         {

             Outlook.ExchangeUser eu = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser();
             if (eu != null)
                senderEmail = eu.PrimarySmtpAddress; 

          }

 }
```